# Wp insert into db exception

Tags: c#, database, exception, windows-phone

My code worked for more than a month, my app parse rss feed (http://www.whitehouse.gov/feed/blog/white-house) and insert news into db:

today I got an exception when app try to add this news "The First Lady's Box at the 2013 State of the Union" to db. here is my code:

```
News item = Query.instance().AddNews(channel.Guid, channel.Description, channel.Link, channel.PublishDate, channel.Title);

   public News AddNews(string guid, string description, string link, DateTime publishDate, string title)
    {
        // create a new and add it to the context
        News item = new News { Guid = guid, Description = description, Link = link, PublishDate = publishDate, Title = title };
        // add the new to the context
        db.NewsItems.InsertOnSubmit(item);
        // save changes to the database
        db.SubmitChanges();

        return item;
    }
```

Imade a debug and the the problem is into description of the news (it seems the lenght), here is the exception:

> "An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.Phone.Data.Internal.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a
>   managed/native boundary A first chance exception of type
>   'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Data.Linq.ni.dll"

and this is the column description into db

```
private string _description;
    [Column]
    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return _description;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_description != value)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("Description");
                _description = value;
                // Remove HTML tags. 
                _description = Regex.Replace(_description, "<[^>]+>", string.Empty);
                // Remove newline characters
                _description = _description.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "");
                // Remove encoded HTML characters
                _description = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(_description);
                //replace spaces
                _description = _description.Replace("  ", "");

                //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_description) && _description.Length > 3900)
                //    _description = _description.Substring(0, 3900);

                NotifyPropertyChanged("Description");
            }
        }
    }
```

when i uncomment this it works:

```
//if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_description) && _description.Length > 3900)
//    _description = _description.Substring(0, 3900);
```

Comment: it seems that the problem is the lenght of the description string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Maris suggests I found the correct solution that is:

```
[Column(DbType = "ntext")] 
public string Description
```

and not

```
[Column(TypeName = "varchar(MAX)")] 
public string Description
```

the second one doesn't work for windows phone ;)

Comment: Ohhh, I missed that you do it for `windows phone`. Yes, you are right

Answer (score 1):

we need the body of the exception to help you with your question. 
But I think(As Emiliano Magliocca said), that the problem is that your Description cell in the DB can hold less chars then you trying to insert. You can fix it changing type of the row Description to varchar(max) or Text. Anyway provide the body of the excpetion, then we will help you.

Asnwer:

You should change the data type of column Description to Varchar(max), then you will feel free to save any amount of text to this collumn, because varchar(max) can hold up to 2gb of text. As you use the codeFirst way to generate the table, use the attribute like that: 
[Column(TypeName = "varchar(MAX)")] 
public string Description...

instead of 
[Column]
public string Description...

Comment: thanks, you're right i forgot to add exception...i added more details...if you can take a look ;)

Comment: Which type of column you are using in table for 'Description'? You should change it to Varchar(max), then you will feel free to save any amount of text to this collumn, because varchar(max) can hold up to 2gb of text. As you use the codeFirst way to generate the table, use the attribute like that:
[Column(TypeName = "varchar(MAX)")]
public string Description...